# Ubuntu only runs from bootable USB and freezes during Live session, not an exact duplicate!

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, usb

I hope someone can help me. I am very independent, so I have tried everything that I found online (and in here). I am new to Ubuntu but love it.

My problem is that I have an Acer Aspire One Cloudbook. Intel Celeron processorN3050, Intel graphics, and a eMMC 32 GB (which is an SD card mounted to board and not a true hard disk drive).

It came preloaded with Windows. It kept telling me I needed to update windows, but when I would try it said no room. I deleted everything and said the same thing. I tried the window reset and basically it screwed up and wouldn't run, so I deleted all partitions and the Windows boot manager, and tried to install Ubuntu. As it happens, I can only run it from the bootable USB and after install it says it is installed, but when I take it out and restart I am told No Bootable Device.

Here are some screenshots I took that will hopefully provide the needed info.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong, but remember I am only learning. I have been taking code courses in block code (I'm trying to learn the Java behind the scenes of it) but I don't think it's going to help me here. I only know a few basic command lines.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to install in UEFI mode.

Comment: Thank you for replying to my question.I have installed in that. I receive a warning when installing that further bios (pragrams?) may not run after but I have installed in every way possible. Perhaps I am doing something wrong with it? I will try again to reinstall and get back to you with what happened.

Comment: Ignore that message and confirm you want UEFI mode. Then it will do it for you. If however you're doing a manual partitioning you need to create a small FAT32 partition that will act as the ESP (EFI System Partition). This partition has to be selected (as EFI) along with all the other typical partitions for Ubuntu that you may have (currently only `/` is required) in "something else".

Comment: Not entirely applicable in your case (unless you want a dual boot) but nevertheless it has a lot of valuable pointers: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi . Then there's also the official docs: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Does it boot to internal drive with the bootable USB plugged in? If so you may have installed grub to the USB and not the internal drive. Try installing using "Something else" and confirm bootloader install location is the root of the hard drive.

Comment: no, it only boots from the USB. I tried reinstalling several times as recommended. but I must have corrupted the file because now it don't ask about the warning and it freezes during certain methods of installation. I am going to try Ubuntu core to see what happens with it.

Comment: Oh and it did something strange. After installation it asked for password, I gave it and it locked me out saying invalid password :(